# How do I integrate my tests to report results to Azure DevOps

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, reporting, specflow

We have a pipeline that handles:
Code pull -> unit tests -> integration tests -> builds artefacts -> deploy
We want our integration tests to report back results to Azure DevOps, how do we do this?
Our test project comprises of .NET codebase that uses SpecFlow to be able to handle the cucumber aspect.
The code reside in a repo on Azure, what is the next step to get this to report to the dashboard?

Comment: Please check the answer and the suggestions to see if it helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [Test Results Trend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#test-results-trend) or [Test Results Trend (Advanced)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#test-trend-results-advanced) widgets for Azure DevOps dashboards.

1. Go to your dashboard.
2. Click the "Edit" button towards the top.
3. The "Add Widget" panel should appear on the right side of the page.
4. Type "test" in the search bar in the "Add Widget" panel.
5. Choose "Test Result Trend" or "Test Result Trend (Advanced)"
6. Select whether you want to monitor tests from a build or release pipeline.
7. Choose the pipeline and number of days to report.